Facing read/write timeout in the middle of Cassandra rolling upgrade from Cassandra 3.0.15 to 4.1.4
Im preparing to upgrade my Cassandra cluster (3 Nodes x 2 DCs) from Cassandra 3.0.15 to 4.1.4, when i tried the upgradation process in a similar setup i faced following issues in the middle of the rolling upgrade.
0) Schema version mismatch:
Cluster status --> DC1 : ( 1 x 4.1.4 )  + ( 2 x 3.0.15 ) && DC2 : 3 x 3.0.15
Schema versions: (Its not an issue)
77876dfb-de1f-3826-89b2-ff6d502bcd6c: [C* 3.0.15 node ips]

        018b628e-98aa-36f4-9e7e-a40cca8bc44d: [C* 4.1.4 node ip]

1) ReadTimeoutException from client
Cluster status --> DC1 : ( 1 x 4.1.4 )  + ( 2 x 3.0.15 ) && DC2 : 3 x 3.0.15
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 responses were required but only 1 replica responded)
Above issue happened when i tried query configuring Cassandra 4.1.4 node as the coordinator node. Query succeeded only after reduced the consistency to LOCAL_ONE.
Things worked smoothly when all the nodes are Cassandra 3.0.15, so there is no network latency.
2) ReadTimeout from CQLSH
Cluster status --> DC1 : ( 1 x 4.1.4 )  + ( 2 x 3.0.15 ) && DC2 : 3 x 3.0.15
ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'consistency': 'ONE', 'required_responses': 1, 'received_responses': 0}
Inconsistently getting above exception when executing query from in the CQL SHELL of the nodes of the DC with mixed versions of Cassandra.

Note : I tried query(SELECT *) a table which has replication factor of 2 via CQL SHELL of each node, I observed that I'm getting
above exception from Cassandra 3.0.15 nodes alone not from Cassandra
4.1.4 node.

3) UnauthorizedException
Cluster status --> DC1 : ( 1 x 4.1.4 )  + ( 2 x 3.0.15 ) && DC2 : 3 x 3.0.15
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnauthorizedException: Unable to perform authorization of super-user permission: Operation timed out - received only 1 responses.

Upgrading to 3.11.15 before upgrading to 4.1.0 is eliminating this issue.

We are facing similar issue from 3.11.14 to 4.1.6 with the timeouts.
@LUCKNESH, can you elaborate on why specifically 3.11.15 will solve this? It's an interesting comment :)

Since 3.11.15 is the latest release in the 3.11 series, we can reasonably believe that it will be compatible with future version upgrades.
It is recommended to upgrade to the latest release of the current version before upgrading to any major version to ensure a seamless upgrade without downtime.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/luna-cassandra/guides/upgrade/overview.html

